# Error file_not_found for popup in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to publish my extension to the Chrome web store. Everything works fine when loaded as an unpacked extension in developer mode. However, when I preview changes after uploading my zip file and try to open the popup, the popup html page appears to be missing with the following error message instead:

> Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
>   ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

There is no error thrown in the console for the popup.

My manifest.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "<name>",
  "version": "0.13",
  "description": "<description>",
  "permissions": ["*://*/*", "identity", "activeTab", "tabs", "storage"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["dist/background/index.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["dist/content_scripts/index.css"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "dist/popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon_16.png",
      "32": "images/icon_32.png",
      "48": "images/icon_48.png",
      "128": "images/icon_128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon_16.png",
    "32": "images/icon_32.png",
    "48": "images/icon_48.png",
    "128": "images/icon_128.png"
  },
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<client_id>",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    ]
  },
  "key": "<my_key>",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

All of the files are in the right place relative to the manifest before compression.

Here are the contents of the popup.html file (popup.js mounts a React app on #root):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.css@7.1.1/themes/reset-min.css" integrity="sha256-JQ2nnTmybhOWSjfV3sa8mG0ZVhTCcORER4cyXc5HL10=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've looked at the Chrome docs but they are either sparse or outdated on this. Can anyone help?

Thanks

(Edit: also I previously uploaded the zip while having forgotten to move the popup.html to the dist/popup folder so that the file was in fact missing, in case that's relevant)

Comment: There's definitely something wrong. Either in your extension or in Chrome. Inspect the installed extension inside the browser profile directory and make sure all paths are correct. I don't see any other explanations without trying the extension myself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I made a mistake between uploading this new version and a previous version. When looking at the Chrome profile in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/<extension_id>` (on Linux) I realised that the last published version was 0.11 which had the popup.html file missing, I had thought that a newer version had been published between (0.12) to fix this but I see that it wasn't.